# How to solve 'The function 'ApplicationBindings' isn't defined' problem?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am new to Getx on Flutter.On Vscode,I created **Getx App Structure**[image] by clicking right mb and this error just occured.Can someone tell me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check that your class is extending **Bindings** in **application_bindings.dart** class. If do so just close your vscode and open it again the error will be gone.

Comment: **application_bindings.dart** is empty bro.What should I do?

Comment: you have to put controller in Binding class :)

Comment: class HomeBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.put(PackageController());
  }
}